# add filter to jquery collagePlus plugin

Tags: jquery, filtering

I am trying to add mixitup to jquery collagePlus but there is an issue when i click on filters
it's working wrong. there is link you can see it

Can any one help me please. how to fix it ?
thanks

Comment: "it's working wrong" - please describe the exact problem. What did you hope would happen, and what is happening instead? Also, please include a concise sample of code that demonstrates the problem inside the question.

Comment: well actually the problem is when you click on filters, filter works but grid is not ok for example click on "Category 1" you can see what happened to grids. here is the source code
http://absalan.com/test/examples/example1.txt

Comment: Did you manage to sort this at all? I am looking at a solution for my problem.

Comment: No unfortunately there is no any solutions for this problem, I contacted the developer but he said i don't have time to add filter to it.Try to find something else...

Answer (score 2):

I was able to do this for a recent project. I took the current demo and modified it. Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// All images need to be loaded for this plugin to work so
// we end up waiting for the whole window to load in this example
$(window).load(function () {
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var orig_images = $('#portfolio').html();
        collage();

        $('.filters a').on('click', function(){
            $('#portfolio').html(orig_images);
            var filterClass = $(this).data('filter');
            $('#portfolio img:not(.' + filterClass + ')').remove();
            $('#portfolio img').css("opacity", 0);
            if (resizeTimer) clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
            resizeTimer = setTimeout(collage, 200);
            return false;
        });
    });
});

// Here we apply the actual CollagePlus plugin
function collage() {
    $('#portfolio').collagePlus(
        {
            'fadeSpeed'     : 2000,
        }
    );
};

// This is just for the case that the browser window is resized
var resizeTimer = null;
$(window).bind('resize', function() {
    $('#portfolio img').css("opacity", 0);
    if (resizeTimer) clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
    resizeTimer = setTimeout(collage, 200);
});
</script>
```

Then here is my HTML:

```
<p align="center" class="filters">
    <a href="#" data-filter="wide">Wide</a>
    <a href="#" data-filter="tall">Tall</a>
</p>
<div id="portfolio"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x300" width="200" height="300" class="tall" /><img src="http://placehold.it/200x300" width="200" height="300" class="tall" /><img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" width="300" height="200" class="wide" /><img src="http://placehold.it/200x300" width="200" height="300" class="tall" /><img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" width="300" height="200" class="wide" /><img src="http://placehold.it/200x300" width="200" height="300" class="tall" /><img src="http://placehold.it/200x300" width="200" height="300" class="tall" /><img src="http://placehold.it/200x300" width="200" height="300" class="tall" /><img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" width="300" height="200" class="wide" /><img src="http://placehold.it/200x300" width="200" height="300" class="tall" /><img src="http://placehold.it/200x300" width="200" height="300" class="tall" /><img src="http://placehold.it/200x300" width="200" height="300" class="tall" /><img src="http://placehold.it/200x300" width="200" height="300" class="tall" /><img src="http://placehold.it/200x300" width="200" height="300" class="tall" /><img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" width="300" height="200" class="wide" /><img src="http://placehold.it/200x300" width="200" height="300" class="tall" /><img src="http://placehold.it/200x300" width="200" height="300" class="tall" /><img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" width="300" height="200" class="wide" /><img src="http://placehold.it/200x300" width="200" height="300" class="tall" /><img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" width="300" height="200" class="wide" /><img src="http://placehold.it/200x300" width="200" height="300" class="tall" /><img src="http://placehold.it/200x300" width="200" height="300" class="tall" /><img src="http://placehold.it/200x300" width="200" height="300" class="tall" /><img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" width="300" height="200" class="wide" /><img src="http://placehold.it/200x300" width="200" height="300" class="tall" /><img src="http://placehold.it/200x300" width="200" height="300" class="tall" /><img src="http://placehold.it/200x300" width="200" height="300" class="tall" /><img src="http://placehold.it/200x300" width="200" height="300" class="tall" /><img src="http://placehold.it/200x300" width="200" height="300" class="tall" /><img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" width="300" height="200" class="wide" /></div>
```

What this is basically doing is on page load, save a copy of the original HTML in the #portfolio div. Assign classes to every image, used as the filter. Added some links to filter with. When a filter link is clicked, it restores the original HTML for the #portfolio div into the #portfolio div. It then removes all images that do not match the clicked filter (hiding the images did not work). Then, re-initiate the collagePlus function on the images that are left.

Comment: I needed the same thing for a client project, thought I would post what I had. I have improved it a little bit, I will post the URL with the final code once it's live.